# Someone has registered multiple domains using my home address. What can I do?

Tags: domain-registration

Someone has registered several domains used as 3rd party pay sites for porn sites using my home address. How do I fix this?

Comment: What problem is it causing?

Comment: Welcome to the ProWebmasters community.  

I don't think there's much you can do about this!

Comment: You have an interesting problem. Are they using the whole address? All the way down to town, state, country, and zip code? If so, I wonder what the payoff would be? Sometimes temporary domain names are used for spam and scamming. These are usually more random. And these generally do not exist too long. A few months to a year at the most. I am racking my brain to think why someone would do this. It makes no sense really. Cheers!!

Comment: You shall contact the registrar and ask it to delete your personnal information.

Comment: Just your address or also your name? If it is with your name, there may be solutions, especially if it is on the registrant part. If it is just your address, probably no solution. How did you come aware of this situation anyway? Did you contact the registrar of those domains, or the registry? You are not even giving the TLD, there are rules and regulations about "false" data.

Comment: @gael How is the registrar supposed to know that there is a single person at that address and that it is not a 1000+ apartments complex? Such kind of (almost impossible) checks are not required from registrars.

Comment: Some registries have requirements on eligibility and for example you need to use a specific geographic place (ex:country). Some checks are in place, sometimes at least that the street name exist, or more complex using postal databases. Reusing content already vouched for and displayed in whois is the simplest way to enter meaningful data that will go through simple scans and not raise suspicions, delays, rejections of domain registration. But this all depends on the TLD that you did not disclose.

Answer (score 1):

Submit a [WHOIS Inaccuracy Complaint](https://forms.icann.org/en/resources/compliance/complaints/whois/inaccuracy-form) to ICANN for the domain or domains involved. They will forward the complaint to the registrar, who will (hopefully?) address it promptly.

Comment: That is a start, however, ICANN is not responsible. They can only contact the registrar and since the e-mail isn't correct, a query will be contacted, by which, they would confirm it. Instead, I would explain whats going on by contacting the registrar's abuse department.